# How to I allow for multiple row returns using subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to output the firstname and secondname of my characters which are active. Only four characters are active at a time, thus

```
SELECT firstname,secondname FROM characters
```

Is incorrect.

When I execute this SQL command:

```
SELECT firstname,secondname FROM characters WHERE charID=(SELECT charID FROM activechar)
```

Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

My Tables are as follows:

[character table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdme5.png)

[activechar table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EidHS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `IN` operator instead:

```
SELECT firstname,secondname FROM characters WHERE charID IN (SELECT charID FROM activechar)
```

The subquery could continue to return multiple rows, but your main query will be able to do a look-up for them.

Answer (score 0):

You could continue using a subquery switching `=` for `IN`, which will check if the left operand is contained in the set that subquery returns. But subqueries with `IN` often don't perform to well. Using an `INNER JOIN`, which will only return rows of both tables, where the condition in the `ON` clause is true, might be a better alternative here.

```
SELECT c.firstname,
       c.secondname
       FROM characters c
            INNER JOIN activechar ac
                       ON ac.charid = c.charid;
```